# Turn on checkbox using BeatifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a form which have a checkbox and a submit button that look like:

```
<form name="create" id="FormCreate" action="/create/0" method="post">
   <div id="condition_D">
      <input type="checkbox" name="condition" title="check me." class="condition" id="condition">
      <label for="condition">You should validate</label>
   </div>
   <div id="submit_D">
      <input type="submit" name="validateButton" value="make a validation" title="Some title">
      <input type="submit" name="cancelButton" value="Cancel" title="Some title">
   </div>
</form>
```

I want to turn the checkbox to on and then make a post request, my code look like:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

header = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36'
}

data = {
    "condition['value']": "on",
    "form_id": "FormCreate",
    "op": "validateButton"
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    url = "http://www.website.com/create/0"
    r = s.get(url, headers=header)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=header)
    print(response.url)
```

This return the same url and same res:

```
http://www.website.com/create/0
```

But it should redirect me to another page.

I search a lot to turn the condition checkbox to on and to make the request but without any success. Any way to solve this problem please?

---

I can find the checkbox using:

```
condition = soup.find('input', attrs={'name': 'condition'})
```

and turn the value to on or true :

```
condition['value'] = 'on'
```

But I don't know how can I proceed the action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know is beautifulsoup just a parser which makes it easier to work with data such as xml or html.

If you want to make a request you can use another library or create you own request. You should use the developer tools in chrome to actually see the request and what parameters are send to the server

The redirection is easily explained that the server just returns a statuscode with the new url. It is the responsibility of the browser (or the script) to perform the neccessary steps.